# Java - object list returns duplicate values

Tags: java, mysql

I'm working on a project that involves the program interacting with an MySQL database, when the query is run to get a certain amount of values from a database, it executes it and then stores the values as an object, eventually passing them to a list.

At the moment, it gets the information from the database okay, passes the variables through okay, but when I go to print the object in that lists name, it returns all the same values (the last value to be passed through).

How would I go about returning all the object values stored in that list?

The code is below:

```
ArrayList<Game> gameDetails = new ArrayList<Game>();

while (rs.next()) {

    String gameName = rs.getString("game");
    int score = rs.getInt("score");
    int time = rs.getInt("time");


    gameDetails.add(new Game(gameName, score, time));

    System.out.println(gameName);
}
for (int i = 0; i < gameDetails.size(); i++) {

    System.out.println(gameDetails.get(i).getName());
}
```

And the Game object class

```
public class Game {

    private static String name = "";
    private static int time = 0, score = 0;

    public Game(String n, int t, int s) {
        this.name = n;
        this.time = t;
        this.score = s;
    }

    public static String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public static int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public static int getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public static void setName(String n) {
        name = n;
    }

    public static void setTime(int t) {
        time = t;
    }

    public static void setScore(int s) {
        score = s;
    }
}
```

At the moment, it returns this value in the console, without the getName() method:

```
Game@516a3a8
Game@6c9844ae
Game@17115812
```

And it returns

```
Call of Duty
Call of Duty
Call of Duty
```

With the getName() method

So it looks like each value is unique, only not when I go to call the getName() method.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Because you are using static variables to hold the Game values, so EVERY game value uses the same instance of these variables, so EVERY game object will have the same values.  Remove static from name, time, and score in Game definition

Answer (score 2):

You are using static member variables in `Game` class. When you declare fields as `private static` members (instead of `private`), these fields are shared across all instances of Game object. Hence every time you change the value of the field e.g. `name` field, value will be updated in the shared reference. Changing the fields to just `private` should work.

```
 private String name = "";
 private int time = 0, score = 0;
```